# Is there a way to update Ad Units for Admob in android app after App Transfer?

Tags: android, firebase, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I have on app which shows ads from AdMob. I have to transfer that app to another person. And I have a problem in updating the Ad units code. I know that I can not update HARDCODED ad unit ids.

But.....

Is there a **Prevention** that I can keep in mind next time I develop an app which contains ads from AdMob, which can be transferred or sold to any other person. --> Such that this problem of ad unit updation does not occur.

I Googled it but can't find any answer which can be called a method for **Prevention**.

Can mediation or firebase used for the prevention?

Comment: Yes, you should use [RemoteConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) from Firebase.

Comment: can it be used even if the app has hard coded ad units or can be just used as prevention?

Comment: nopes, you need to code in advance before releasing to playstore.

Comment: You can use the Firebase Remote Config to store the ad id online and then display the ads using that id. So that you can change that id aytime.